# How to ignore the hidden element in selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hidden-field

I have written an script using selenium for user addition to an application. In which inside 'for loop' there is a `Add_Button` which will be visible at the start(i.e first user addition). While addiding the second user script will search for the hidden element `Add_Button`, but its not available so I am getting error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element
```

I need to skip the click of the `Add_Button` while second user addition in the for loop. I had tried the following codes, but no luck yet. Please help me with this.

1st try:    Not working

```
if(browser.findElements(By.id("ext-gen72")).size()!=0){

browser.findElement(By.id("ext-gen72")).click();

}
```

2nd Try: Not working

```
int k=0;

 boolean doneOnce=false;

 do{

 if (!doneOnce) {

                  //execute this only one time
                  browser.findElement(By.id("ext-gen72")).click();
                  doneOnce=true;

                  }

//rest of the code....

}While(k>10);
```

Answer (score 0):

WebElement visible status can be found using `isDisplayed()` method if the element is present on page. If the element is not present on the page it will throw `NoSuchElement` exception.

```
if(browser.findElement(By.id("ext-gen72")).isDisplayed())
 browser.findElement(By.id("ext-gen72")).click();
```

If element is not present on the page once clicked, you can use below code:

```
int k=0;
boolean clickOnce=true;

do{
 if (clickOnce) {
  browser.findElement(By.id("ext-gen72")).click();
  clickOnce=false;
  }
  // rest of the code
}While(k>10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((JavascriptExecutor)browser).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", browser.findElement(By.id("ext-gen72"));
```

Sometimes, a hidden element is visible on the page, but the driver just can't seem to get ahold of it.  You can use JavaScriptExecutor to work around this by calling the javascript click() method on the element, provided that the element exists on the page.

Comment: Could you elaborate this a bit?

Comment: elaborated a little bit on my previous answer.

Comment: Can you please explain more on this. I'm getting error "JavaScriptExecutor" cannot be resolved into a type" while using the above code.

Comment: My capitalization may be off.  https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
List<WebElement> elements = browser.findElements(By.id("ext-gen72"));       if(elements.size()!=0){
                        for(WebElement element:elements){
                if(element.isEnabled()){
                    element.click();
                }           }
```